# Latest Foursquare Checkin function

Tags: functions

Does anyone know how to display the latest Foursquare checkin for a specific account on a WordPress blog?

Ideally I would like to add the function to the theme rather than use a plugin but i'm open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for you:

First download [this nice little class](http://code.google.com/p/foursquare-php/)

Next, include it and “login”

```
<?php
require_once 'foursquare.php'; //Load the foursquare class
$foursquare = new fourSquare("username", "password"); //login
```

Then to get the venue’s name use:

```
<?php echo $foursquare->venueName; ?>
```

you can also get the venue's type,venue's icon, venue's location on the map and user’s comment on the venue. its all documented at the link provided above.

### Update:

Since FourSquare changed their API i found a much simpler solution:
login to your foursquare account and then head to http://feeds.foursquare.com/ and copy the rss feed url.
and use this:

```
// $numCheckins - number of checkins to get
function Display_last_checkins($numCheckins = 2){
    $feedURL = 'enter your rss feed here';
    $feedObject = simplexml_load_file($feedURL . '?count=' .$numCheckins);
    $items = $feedObject->channel;
    $checkin = $items->item;
    echo '<ul>';
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($checkin as $item) {
        if ($item->link != '') {
            echo '<li><a href="'. $item->link .'">' .
                $item->title . '</a><br/></li>';
            /* you can use 
            $item->description  - user comment
            $item->pubDate      - publish date and time (Wed, 27 Apr 11 16:40:18 +0000)
            $item->georss:point - location for map (31.613221 34.76874)

            */
            $count++;
            if ($count == $numCheckins) {break;}
        }
    }
    $echo .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Some caching will do good :)

Comment: Hi Bainternet, I've included the above and it's authorising (I deliberately broke it and got the password error) however the actual echo isn't working? Any ideas?

Comment: create a pastebin of the exact code you are using

Comment: Yep found it, FourSquare changed there API at 1st of august, so its a bit out dated , ill take a look at there API and what i can come up with.

Comment: I added a new solution.

Comment: Hi I add this in but it doesn't output anything, have I missed something?

Comment: probably because its tested  and working well, put the function in your theme's functions.php and call it whenever you want but don't forget to update your rss feed